# What's my dwarf mumbling about, it's not a material?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a children with a strange mood that keeps muttering about Duradkàs and my only question is... what in Armok is Duradkàs? I was thinking about a instrument, but u->m->q doesn't reveal that my dwarves can build that nor does the stock menu. grep'd the raw directory for duradk and found nothing, durad means beard in dwarven language, but I can't believe the child is constructing a beard artifact... I don't want to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Artifact names are just random compound words, in Dwarvish. If the kid finishes his artifact, you'll find out the intended translation, which very well may be something like "The Beard of Quiet" despite having nothing to do with beards (durad) or quiet (kàs I think, although the accent makes it hard to search for). Since he's a child, he doesn't have any useful skills, so he'll be making some kind of rockcraft (if you're lucky) or wood- or bonecraft (if you're not) object, and you'll find out what it is when he's finished!

Also, what is wrong with a child creating a beard artifact? He needs to keep his beard long and silky somehow!

Comment: I was about to write the answer about this. Yes, it was a Beard Mask (however that works), so the mumblings is basically the name of the artifact. Will change the title to make it more general.

Comment: Hi Paul! I just want to add to your answer that hopefully there is an accessible applicable workshop for the child to claim.